# Find the best parameters that give the centreline of a cylinder by optimization

Tags: image-processing, optimization, scipy, 3d, computer-vision

please forgive me as this is my first post if in case it's not written in the best way. I am desperate for help. In the following function, I am trying to find the centreline of a 3D cylinder by optimization. The idea is to use the Maurer distance map(Euclidian transform) of the cylinder image. How? I have the center of the circle of a cylinder. I construct a line from that center, by providing 2 angles(parameters) and length(fixed) to get the endpoint of the line(since we are in 3D).

I find the equidistant points between the center and the endpoint and find the eucledian distance transform at these indices. In other words, the voxel values of the maurer distance map image at these indices. Then I add them up and divide it by the number of points to return the score.

What I want to achieve is the angles that fit the centreline of the cylinder that return the smallest score when I optimise.

```
def func_cost(params):



 """Calculates vector from center of cylinder by giving angle and length.
    Finds the endpoint then splits it into equidistant points between the center and the          endpoint.
    Calculates Maurer Distance map(EDT) on these points. Fetches the voxel values from these points, adds them up and divides by the number of points
    Returns the Score"""

    length = 100
    center = np.array([50, 50, 80])
    ep_x = center[0] + length * np.cos(np.deg2rad(params[0])) * np.sin(
        np.deg2rad(params[1])
    )
    ep_y = center[1] + length * np.cos(np.deg2rad(params[0])) * np.cos(
        np.deg2rad(params[1])
    )
    ep_z = center[2] + length * np.sin(np.deg2rad(params[0]))

    endpoint = np.array([ep_x, ep_y, ep_z])
    print("Epx", ep_x, "epy", ep_y, "epz", ep_z)
    print("Endpoint", endpoint)
    Vec = endpoint - center
    vector = np.linalg.norm(Vec, axis=0)
    print("Vector length is", vector)
    allsamples = []
    if endpoint.ndim == 1:
        samples = np.array(list(getEquidistantPoints(center, endpoint, 5))) 
        allsamples.append(samples)
        allsamples = np.array(allsamples)

    else:
        for index in range(endpoint.shape[0]):
            samples = np.array(
                list(getEquidistantPoints(center, endpoint[index], 5))
            )  # Splits the vector from center till endpoint into equidistant points
            # print("samples", samples)
            allsamples.append(samples)
        allsamples = np.array(allsamples)
    print("All samples", allsamples)

    vox_idx = []
    vox_list = []

    """ For each endpoint and the splits between the center and the endpoint, fetch me the voxel value at the image index """

    for i in range(allsamples.shape[0]):
        for j in range(allsamples.shape[1]):
            indices_img = mdmap.TransformPhysicalPointToIndex(allsamples[i][j]) 
            #mdmap is the euclidian distance transform image
            max_voxel = np.amax(mdmap_arr)
            try:
                vox_val = mdmap_arr[indices_img]
                print(vox_val)
                vox_list.append(vox_val)
                vox_idx.append(indices_img)
            except:
                limit = (
                    max_voxel + 10
                )  # If indices are outside the image, add the max voxel value by a threshold and assign it to index outside the image
                print(
                    "Image indices out of bounds for sample",
                    indices_img,
                )
                vox_list.append(
                    limit
                )  # Add maximum voxel value to list for indices bouncing out of the image
    print("Voxel list", vox_list)
    vox_chunks = [
        vox_list[x : x + samples.shape[0]]
        for x in range(0, len(vox_list), samples.shape[0])
    ]  # Divide the whole voxel list into chunks of num_points
    print(vox_chunks)
    s = np.array(
        list(map(sum, vox_chunks))
    )  # Find the sum of voxels for every chunk
    print(s)
    num = samples.shape[0]
    score = np.array(s) / num  # Average score
    print("Chunk score", score)
    return np.amin(score)  # Returns minimum score out of all scores`
    #Function ends here 

x0 = np.array([90,90])
res = minimize(func_cost, x0, method='nelder-mead')
```

**Here, the optimiser just gives me the initial guess I give even if I change the x0 value. What I want is that no matter what x0 I give, I should get the value of the parameters that give me the smallest score and hence the parameters that give me that. Any ways to fix this?
Thanks a lot**

Comment: What's the rationale of using the Maurer distance ? If your image is binary, it has lost all valuable orientation information.

Comment: I do have a binary image and its a given that I use that :/

Comment: Can we see it ?

Comment: Well I make the image on an np array in a very dirty way using the equation of a cylinder and use sitk to construct an image